# R: Is a vector in a list of vectors

Tags: r, list, vector, equality

Suppose that you have a simple vector, say `c(2,3)` and you want to check if it is in a list of vectors, say `list(c(2,1), c(3,2), c(2,3))`. That is, you want TRUE to be returned if c(2,3) is in this list and FALSE otherwise. Does R have any built-in function to do this? I could build a function for it, but I find it hard to believe that a language where almost everything is a vector doesn't have a simple way to check if a vector is in a list of vectors.

Comment: @dww That was just stupidity on my part. Fixed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

```
l = list(c(2,1), c(3,2), c(2,3))
x = c(3,2)
any(sapply(l, identical, x))
```

Comment: That's better than what I had in mind for writing it myself, but I'm still shocked that there's not a build-in function for this.